# Monitor Color Calibration

Tags: linux, windows, multiple-monitors, thinkpad, color-profiles

I would like to perform color calibration on a significantly large number of monitors that I use on a daily basis.  I don't currently have a standalone colorimeter.  What I ***do*** have is a workstation-class laptop (a ThinkPad P71) which includes auto-calibration features, including a colorimeter in its palm rest.

Would it be possible to use the colorimeter in the ThinkPad to calibrate an external monitor?  All the monitors I want to calibrate can easily be attached to the ThinkPad.

If I were to calibrate the monitor, create the profile, move the monitor to another machine, and input the profile, would the profile still work with the different video configuration of the other machine?  If so, would I be able to use the colorimeter in the ThinkPad to calibrate a monitor attached to a different machine?

The ThinkPad has Windows, Ubuntu Linux, and FreeBSD installed on it, so any of those would work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the built-in colorimeter seals tight to the laptop screen with the lid closed by some means.

If the laptop will fold out totally flat so you could apply it with the same quality of light seal to another display, then you have at least a start-point - you'd then need to track down the profile it made on the laptop & persuade the OS on the display's usual computer to use it as default.
In theory, changing the GPU etc as you swap machines should not affect this calibration. You will have to switch off any 'user-friendly' automatic colour temperature variation on the recipient machine (but this is usually a requirement for any machine with any kind of 'helpful' colour modification built-in.)

Such as [DisplayCAL](https://displaycal.net) might go some way towards this separation of newly-made profile from underlying 'wrong computer', but this is not something I've ever tried to tackle with anything other than a regular portable colorimeter & appropriate software installed to the correct computer.

Comment: Thank you very much!